# Html5Boilerplate or Html5Boilerplate Mobile for mobile-first website?

Tags: html, mobile, mobile-website, html5boilerplate

Now that [Html5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) has reached version 2.0 and is oriented around mobile-first design, should [Html5Boilerplate Mobile](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile) still be used for mobile-first sites?  Just wanted to ask b/f I dig through the code of each.

It appears one of the obvious differences is that Html5Boilerplate has switched from CSS reset to normalize, and added mobile-first aspects like respond.js and mobile media query sections.  Standard boilerplate appears more active on Github as well.  Anyone have any opinion about these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Html5Boilerplate Mobile should not be used for new projects; it is deprecated.

A deprecation notice [was added](https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate/commit/78c876e065d90fa87eb55b04b7c127769d66dc54) in July 2015 to the project's [GitHub repo](https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate) (as of this answering -- Aug 2016 -- that was the most recent commit):

> The H5BP team decided to no longer maintain Mobile Boilerplate since
>   HTML5 Boilerplate seems to be a good starting point for any kind of
>   project.

Answer (score 23):

Stealing this answer mostly from [our mailing list thread on the subject](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en_US#!msg/html5boilerplate/dNbB8ZGFNcM/u94fhLeVCg8J)...

> HTML5Boilerplate is the one you should use if you are getting started
>   on websites. It is optimized to work and adapt on mobile browsers.
>
> Mobile HTML5 Boilerplate is optimized for web apps that are explicitly
>   written to have different UX while on devices other than the desktop.
>
> - This means they might want to imitate the UI of native applications
>     or be close to it.
> - They may make heavy use of touch-based UI paradigms and other
>     interactions that are not possible on a desktop browser.
> - They explictly use media queries and other ways to detect a
>     non-desktop browser and serve an experience that is different.
>
> When I say web apps, I mean websites that are used intensively to
>   accomplish certain tasks (like twitter.com / gmail.com / facebook.com
>   / admin interface of wordpress.com ). These sites are required to take
>   advantage of the space available and help users accomplish their tasks
>   with minimal effort no matter what device.
>
> On the other hand, we do have websites that users visit occasionally
>   because they found it on some friend's email or on reddit which has
>   content but users rarely interact with it (other than just visiting it
>   or at most leaving a comment), in which case html5 boilerplate would
>   be a good template to use. This would be a good option for most sites
>   that are content-rich and require minimal user interaction.
>
> Unfortunately for us, mobile platforms are also creating silos by
>   specifying custom meta tags to use to optimize for their platform.
>   E.g. Apple recommends using apple-touch-icon meta tag to specify
>   things specific to webkit mobile browsers. Nokia has its own. We did
>   not want html5boilerplate to add such cruft to the defaults, but this
>   would be necessary for someone writing an application tailored to take
>   advantage of non-desktop devices. There is already a lot of
>   consistency, but we wish there was more standardization of mobile
>   optimizations.

We are planning an update to the mobile version with the newer files
as well, but there is no significant disadvantage to using it today. We do not yet have a meeting point where we could just have one project, but we are hoping in the future it does
merge into one :)

Comment: I am wondering if I can use a backwards approach and use BPMobile for both desktop-web AND mobile-web. I am working on a project right now that uses a lot of jQuery animations such as paralax and JSclouds which runs very slow and laggish on mobile devices. I want the same UX for both environments. I am using mediaQueries to use smaller images/elements for smaller screens, but this doesn't seem to optimize mobile performance like I thought it would. How can I make these particular effects run smoothly on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on approach. Use HTML5 BP if you are going to have same mark-up for you mobile and desktop website. but if you are making separate website for mobile then go for Mobile Boiler Plate